# Div overlapping another elements making it non clickable tailwindcss

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwindcss inn reactjs which has div element divided into two parts, one is 9-12 and the second is 3-12. The 9-12 part is overlapping navbar one element and I'm able to click that element, but the 3-12 part overlaps 3 elements i.e. Experinece, Projet and Contact in navbar, which is not clickable.
Here's the code for navbar section:

```
<nav className="bg-gray-900 fixed w-full">
        <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-8">
          <div className="flex items-center justify-between h-24">
            <div className="w-full justify-between flex items-center">
              <a className="flex-shrink-0" href="/">
                <img
                  className="h-20 w-20 mt-4"
                  src={logo}
                  alt="Pradeep Anand"
                />
              </a>
              <div className="hidden md:block">
                <div className="ml-10 flex items-baseline space-x-4">
                  <a
                    className="text-gray-300 hover:text-pink-600 dark:hover:text-white px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium duration-300"
                    data-aos="fade-down"
                    data-aos-duration="1000"
                    data-aos-anchor-placement="top-center"
                    href="/#"
                  >
                    About
                  </a>
                  <a
                    className="text-gray-300 hover:text-pink-600 dark:hover:text-white px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium duration-300"
                    data-aos="fade-down"
                    data-aos-delay="100"
                    data-aos-duration="1000"
                    data-aos-anchor-placement="top-center"
                    href="/#"
                  >
                    Experience
                  </a>
                  <a
                    className="text-gray-300  hover:text-pink-600 dark:hover:text-white px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium duration-300"
                    data-aos="fade-down"
                    data-aos-delay="200"
                    data-aos-duration="1000"
                    data-aos-anchor-placement="top-center"
                    href="/#"
                  >
                    Project
                  </a>
                  <a
                    className="text-gray-300  hover:text-pink-600 dark:hover:text-white px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium duration-300"
                    data-aos="fade-down"
                    data-aos-delay="300"
                    data-aos-duration="1000"
                    data-aos-anchor-placement="top-center"
                    href="/#"
                  >
                    Contact
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="block">
              <div className="ml-4 flex items-center md:ml-6"></div>
            </div>
            <div className="-mr-2 flex md:hidden">
              <button className="text-gray-800 dark:text-white hover:text-gray-300 inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md focus:outline-none">
                <svg
                  width="20"
                  height="20"
                  fill="currentColor"
                  className="h-8 w-8"
                  viewBox="0 0 1792 1792"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <path d="M1664 1344v128q0 26-19 45t-45 19h-1408q-26 0-45-19t-19-45v-128q0-26 19-45t45-19h1408q26 0 45 19t19 45zm0-512v128q0 26-19 45t-45 19h-1408q-26 0-45-19t-19-45v-128q0-26 19-45t45-19h1408q26 0 45 19t19 45zm0-512v128q0 26-19 45t-45 19h-1408q-26 0-45-19t-19-45v-128q0-26 19-45t45-19h1408q26 0 45 19t19 45z"></path>
                </svg>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Here's the code for another component:

```
<div className="flex px-48 flex-wrap">
        <div className="w-9/12 pt-32 pb-10">
          <h2
            className="text-2xl text-pink-600 intro"
            data-aos="fade-up"
            data-aos-delay="300"
            data-aos-duration="1000"
            data-aos-anchor-placement="top-center"
          >
            Hi, my name is
          </h2>
          <br />
          <h1
            className="text-8xl"
            data-aos="fade-up"
            data-aos-delay="500"
            data-aos-duration="1000"
            data-aos-anchor-placement="top-center"
          >
            Pradeep
            <br />
            Anand
          </h1>
          <div
            className="w-16 h-2 bg-pink-800 mt-3"
            data-aos="fade-right"
            data-aos-delay="300"
            data-aos-anchor-placement="top-bottom"
          />
          <button
            className="my-28 px-6 py-4 transition ease-in duration-200 uppercase rounded-md hover:bg-pink-800 hover:bg-opacity-30 hover:text-white border-2 border-pink-900 focus:outline-none"
            data-aos="fade-up"
            data-aos-delay="500"
            data-aos-duration="1000"
            data-aos-anchor-placement="top-bottom"
          >
            Get In Touch
          </button>
        </div>
        <div
          className="w-3/12 pt-48"
          data-aos="fade-left"
          data-aos-delay="800"
          data-aos-duration="1000"
          data-aos-anchor-placement="top-center"
        >
          <h3 className="text-sm text-pink-800 font-bold intro">
            Introduction
          </h3>
          <h4 className="text-4xl py-4">
            Software Developer by Profession. Web Dev by passion.
          </h4>
          <p>I'm a software engineer from India. I make things for web.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[image]

Comment: please provide a working sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please provide z-index to the nav bar to avoid this . since it has position fixed property

Comment: thanks, it works! I tried z-index on each element and it didn't work. now I tried z-index on nav element. It worked.